# My global variable comes back as undefined (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

I'm really struggling with basic Javascript here... basically, I'm trying to make a function that, when called, sets two variables (longitude and latitude) so that I can run other functions straight afterwards that uses these values.

When I try to alert out the longitude value however, it comes back undefined.

Here's my code.

```
var latitude;    
var longitude;

function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayLocation);
  } else {
    alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
  }
}

function displayLocation(position, latitude, longitude) {
  latitude = position.coords.latitude;
  longitude = position.coords.longitude;
  return;
}

function newLocation(longitude) {
  alert(longitude);
}

window.onload = function() {
  getLocation(); 
  newLocation();
}
```

Any help will be seriously appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: hint: anytime a function takes another function as an argument, you can betcha the function being passed won't be called immediately (or will be called multiple times).

Comment: at what point does it show undefined?

Comment: @kennypu in the alert, I guess ;-)

Comment: also, in your displayLocation, you have latitude, and longitude as parameters. I'm assuming those are getting set (the parameter), instead of your global variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems with the code you posted:

The arguments to `displayLocation` are hiding your global variables. When you make the assignments here, you are actually assigning to your argument variables, which are in the local scope.

```
function displayLocation(position, latitude, longitude) {
  latitude = position.coords.latitude;
  longitude = position.coords.longitude;
}
```

IIRC, the callback to geolocation.getCurrentPosition only takes the first argument, so you shouldn't have to define the `latitude` and `longitude` as arguments.

Same problem in the `newLocation` function. You call it without arguments, but the `longitude` argument is "hiding" the global variable.

These are small syntax problems. However there is another problem in the code, which is a bit trickier to solve.

When the page is loaded, you call the two functions sequentially:

```
window.onload = function() {
    getLocation(); 
    newLocation();
}
```

The second function, `newLocation`, expects that `getLocation` has set the global variables. This, however, may not be the case. When the `getLocation` function calls `geolocation.getCurrentPosition`, it's performing an **asynchronous operation**. The next line after the call continues to execute immediately, but the callback function `displayLocation` has not necessarily been called yet. This can be a bit complicated to understand at first, but basically you need to only call `newLocation` **after** `displayLocation` has run.

So it gets complicated? That's why it's considered a good practice to try to avoid global variables altogether. Javascript often forces us to do asynchronous programming, and trying to understand all the possible states in which the global variables could be at any given time could drive you mad.

Instead, if possible, you should always use function arguments directly. For example in your scenario, you could skip the `displayLocation` step entirely, and go straight to `newLocation`:

```
function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(newLocation);
  } else {
    alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
  }
}

function newLocation(position) {
    alert(position.longitude);
}
```

So global variables are no longer needed.

I'm sure that the example code you posted is simplified, and your actual code is more complicated, but if you're able to follow these principles, I think you'll have a better time with javascript.

Comment: Thankyou so much for responding. So basically, I'm running 'newLocation()', and the variables haven't even been set yet?

Is there a way to call 'newLocation()' only after 'getLocation()' has been called, that doesn't require me to do it from within the function itself?

Comment: @LiamRichardson, I edited my answer in response to your question.

Comment: Thankyou so much. I think I'm just too afraid to keep repeating the code contained within that initial getLocation variable, thinking it's bad practice to do so at multiple points throughout my JavaScript file.

Thanks again for your advice! You've been a fantastic help!

Comment: @LiamRichardson, you're welcome, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Javascript (and programming) is difficult at first, so it's good to ask questions. That's what this place is for. If you got the answers you needed, please mark the question answered by accepting the most helpful answer.

Comment: Done and done. Thanks for taking the time to point me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 2):

You never assign anything to your global variables.

The assignments in `displayLocation` refer to the function parameters `latitude`/`longitude` (which are local variables in the function), not the global variables outside.

Wrong:

```
var x;

function foo(x) {
  x = 42; // ^ assigns to this x, not the global variable
}

foo(0);
alert(x);  // undefined
```

Right:

```
var x;

function foo() {
  x = 42;  // no local x in scope here
}

foo();
alert(x);  // 42
```

Comment: Even if he did, he's logging the globals too soon.

Comment: I don't? Am I doing something wrong in the displayLocation function?

Comment: @Liam You're assigning to the arguments passed, not to the global variables of the same name.

Comment: How would I go about fixing this? Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

I find 2 problems in your code.

First,in function `displayLocation` , you use 2 variable `latitude` and `longitude`, they refer to local variable as function arguments, not the global ones. To fix this ,remove the last 2 function arguments like this: `displayLocation(position)` or use `window.latitude`,`window.longitude` instead(not recommended).

Second,`displayLocation` is a callback function which will be called after event is triggered, in your case, after browser get the location.So you don't know when `displayLocation` is called. If you call `newLocation()` , maybe `displayLocation` has already been called and `latitude`,`longitude` has refreshed, maybe not. So you should put `alert(longitude);` in `displayLocation` function to ensure `latitude`,`longitude` is refreshed.

hope these help.